# LitElement click function is executed twice

Tags: javascript, typescript, lit-element

i have two components `sdk-button` and an `upper-component`

in my `sdk-button` i have the following simple code:

```
public render() {
    return html`
    <button  @click=${this._handleClick}>${this.text}</button>

`;
}

_handleClick() {
    let click = new Event('click');
    this.dispatchEvent(click);
}
```

This dispatches a click event so in my `upper-component` i have the following code:

```
public render() {
    return html`
  <h1>Hello, ${this.test}!</h1>
  <sdk-button   @click="${() => { this.changeProperty() }}" text="Click"></sdk-button>
`;
}

changeProperty() {
    let randomString = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100).toString();
    console.log(randomString)
}
```

This works however the `changeProperty` is fired twice. can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: You can prevent default behaviour of button click with `e.preventDefault()` which makes click triggers only in dispatch event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure that's because there are two click events: the native one from the button which bubbles up, and the one you dispatch manually. Try to either use a custom event with a different name or remove the dispatch from the `sdk-button` and use the native one.